# Android RSA key length

Tags: android, security, rsa, keystore, encryption-asymmetric

I would like to generate and store securely a 4096 bit RSA key pair on an Android device running API 18+ (4.3). The documentation states the AndroidKeyStore supports 4096 bit keys on API 18. However there is no method/way for setting the key length using the KeyPairGeneratorSpec. The setKeyLength and the setAlgorithmParameterSpec are API 19+. Since the documentation claims that the 4096 key length is supported there has to be some way of setting that.

Comment: The AndroidKeyStore always had more features than accessible through it's public API. See the blog post [Credential storage enhancements in Android 4.3](https://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html).

Comment: @Robert: That blog posts specifically says the keysize cannot be changed from the default of 2048.

Comment: any answer on this?